# What is the difference between test, [, and [[ in terms of binary vs. builtin?

Tags: bash, test, shell-builtin

It is often written:

- `/usr/bin/test` is a synonym for `/usr/bin/[`
- `[[` is a bash improvement for `[`
- `test` and `[` are also builtins

I understand the difference between `[` and `[[` but I am confused with the *binary* vs. *builtin* relationship here. What is really used in my scripts when I use `[` or `[[` if `/usr/bin/test` and `/usr/bin/[` are also present in my system?

In the manpage for `test`, there is missing the often-used option `-a`, which is listed in `help test`. I would guess `[` is used as a builtin, if this option works.